# RSpec expectations from(...).to(...) returning error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have the following code:

```rb
it 'draws one h-segment of colour C' do
  editor.send :create_image, 3, 2
  pp editor.image

  expect {
    pp editor.image # => [["O", "O", "O"], ["O", "O", "O"]]
    editor.send :draw_horizontal, 0, 1, 0, 'C'
    pp editor.image # => [["C", "C", "O"], ["O", "O", "O"]]
  }.to change{
    editor.image
  }.
  from([["O", "O", "O"], ["O", "O", "O"]]). 
  to   [["C", "C", "O"], ["O", "O", "O"]]

end
```

Because both lines before and after invoking the method `:draw_horizontal` are returning what I have in the `from` and `to` matchers, I was hoping the test to pass.

Actually, I'm getting the this error:

> > ```
> > Failure/Error: expect {
> >    expected result to have initially been [["O", "O", "O"], ["O", "O", "O"]], but was [["C", "C", "O"], ["O", "O", "O"]]
> > ```

I tried also to remove the `from` and leaving only the `to` but that way the result is

> > ```
> > Failure/Error: expect {
> >    expected result to have changed to [["C", "C", "O"], ["O", "O", "O"]], but did not change
> > ```

Any ideas how to fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the solution suggested by @benjamin-sinclaire but unfortunately didn't work.

To fix this issue I had to evaluate the `.to_s` of the `Array` instead of it's value itself.
I don't know if this was comparing the content of the variable `@image` passed by-reference instead of by-value.

```
it 'draws one h-segment of colour C' do
  expect {
    editor.send(:draw_horizontal, 0, 1, 0, 'C')
  }.to change { editor.image.to_s }.
  from([["O", "O", "O"], ["O", "O", "O"]].to_s).
  to   [["C", "C", "O"], ["O", "O", "O"]].to_s

end
```

It works well this way, but if you find another (better) solution and explanation please comment below.

Comment: Good job. A cleaner way could be to use `inspect`. It gives the same result on array, but it's a good habit to use `inspect` because it works with almost everything in Ruby.

Answer (score -1):

It's a blind guess, but try this

```
describe 'isolate this block to use `subject`' do # You'll have to name this accordingly
  subject { editor }
  before { editor.send :create_image, 3, 2 }
  it 'draws one h-segment of colour C' do
    expect { editor.send :draw_horizontal, 0, 1, 0, 'C' }.
    to change(:image).
    from([["O", "O", "O"], ["O", "O", "O"]]). 
    to   [["C", "C", "O"], ["O", "O", "O"]]
  end
end
```